# Push Notification from server

Tags: android, push-notification

I have developed an app in which i am collecting data from server through parsing. So , i want to add push notification in my app whenever the service adds new data. I have searched the web bt cldn't fnd smthn useful.

Comment: Maybe you should go over your open questions once in a while and mark the most helpful comments. This will make sure you keep getting answers. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to either get a webserver with cronjob this will send information directly to your mobile ... or, to make an backgroundservice in your application.

It's not a simple thing to do, in the upcomming few days I'll be posting a tutorial on http://p-xr.com wich explains it in detail.